# How does a single MySQL server instance balance loads between databases?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two databases running on a single server.  One is for development and the other is a production site which gets 1 or 2 hits per second on a large database resulting in a fairly heavy server load.

I've noticed that running the same routines on the live database is much slower than the other and can only assume this is due to the amount of queries it's receiving from web traffic.

Why exactly does one database have such slow response times while the other processes the same queries much quicker even though both are running on the same server?  Is this a matter of many requests competing for access to the same resource or is there a specific limit assigned to each database?

And is there a way to distribute the load somehow so that the server can allot more power to the production database?

Comment: There is a nice answer to this question in Stack Exchange DBA. Check it out http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/load-balanced-mysql-cluster-without-load-balancer

Comment: @Aditya That's not the same question at all — quite the opposite.

Comment: I suggest deleting this question and asking on [dba.se] with more details. What operating system? Are the databases on the same disk? Is it RAID? SSD? How large are the databases? How complex are the tables involved in the queries? Do you have approximate timing statistics? Do you have MySQL slow query logging enabled, and what appears there?

Comment: As I understand it, http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is for professional dbas, which I am not.  The rest of your questions seem somewhat irrelevant as I am primarily just looking for an explanation about how MySQL handles load between different databases on the same server.

Comment: In PHP if 500 processes run one script and only 1 process runs a seconds script, I don't expect the first script to under-perform. I am assuming the database behaves differently, since MySQL is actually accessing data on the disk, but to be honest I don't really understand the mechanics of it.